# Autobias Vbe with output current sensing

Tags: amplifier, analog, bias

this is a question about analog audio amplifiers and automatic regulation of the output stage bias circuitry.

I basically need to implement an autobias circuit on this output stage topology:
[image]

As you can see, it's a very simple and classic output stage, the entire amplifier is a classical three-stage: input, VAS and output.

The target, is to use one o more transistor to sense the current flowing in the output transistor and regulating the bias accordingly. Obviously, without using thermal compensation and putting the Vbe transistor on the heatsink.

I found on Douglas Self's book *"Audio Amplifier Design Handbook (6th ed)"* a circuit capable of doing it:

[image]

He use a differential to regulate the current of Tr13, but I can't understand what is V_Ref.

Can you help me to understand how this circuit works? And how to implement this on a common amplifier output stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to understand is that "dynamic bias" gimmicks are mostly useless. Let's do a simulation:

[image]

"V4" is a voltage source which drives this output stage. I've replaced the CFP lower transistor with a darlington, besides that it should work like the original.

The diff pair Q15,Q16 compares the voltage on emitter resistors R16,R17 with reference V3. I labeled both emitters e1,e2 on the schematic so the voltage between them is v(e1,e2). I set reference V3 to 66mV, R16+R17 in series make 0.66 ohms, so we have idle current of 100mA.

The output of this diff pair drives Q13. When v(e1,e2) is too high relative to desired bias voltage V3, Q13 conducts more and shunts some current, discharging C4, which reduces v(e1,e2).

When v(e1,e2) is too low, Q13 conducts less, thus voltage on C4 increases, also increasing v(e1,e2).

This works nicely until a load is connected to the amplifier and it draws enough output current to **pull the amp out of class A**.

As long as output current is low enough to stay in class A, that is as long as both both output transistors conduct, then this scheme will keep v(e1,e2) constant as desired. **This would make it pretty good for a pure class A amplifier.**

However, when output current exceeds what class A can provide then one of the transistors will turn off, and voltage on the other emitter resistor will increase as current increases. Say Q9 turns off, then v(e2)=v(out) since there is no current in R17, and all the output current flows through R16. If output voltage increases, and output current increases, then v(e1,e2) will be greater than the reference voltage... and Q13 will turn on hard, discharging C4. Since C4 can only charge through current source I2, until it is charged again to the desired bias voltage, the amp will be underbiased and run in class B, producing huge crossover distortion as shown on the simulation below:

[image]

Curves from top to bottom:

Input and output voltage (showing crossover distortion)

Emitter current of both output transistors. At the beginning, they are biased at 100mA each without signal.

v(e1,e2) is the voltage on both emitter resistors

v(c4) is the bias voltage

ie(Q15) and ie(Q16) are currents through the diff pair... it does clip...

ie(Q13) is the current through the shunt transistor Q13, which becomes quite chaotic as soon as output current exceeds Class-A current...

In other words, this would work for class A, but definitely not for class AB, so unless you want a space heater this is only for headphone amps... I'm sure Self mentions this, right?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have a question: an example of autobias integrated circuit is the Analog LT1166, it's for poweramps tube and solid. There is a circuit like this useable that is not the LT1166?

Comment: I don't know of any other. If you want to implement it in discrete you'll need precision matched transistors which will be expensive.

Comment: Another thing, you have not used a resistor in your simulation, that in schematic is R14 (1kOhm). The simulation was the same?

Comment: Yes, R14 biases Vref. This would be required for a real Vref component but not for a simulation voltage source

Answer (score 1):

The circuit IS useless outside of class A. But this is happening with any other Bias solution like Vbe multiplier.

This is constant current source with discrete differential amplifier.

But inside the class A, there are some advantages:

1. current is more constant than classic Vbe multiplier because of negative feedback from resistors
2. current is completely independent of temperature. This point is specially important for class A amplifiers, because quiescent currents are high and output transistors are running at pretty high temperature 100% of time.
3. setting current is much easier, and LINEAR dependent from reference voltage. I think Vbe multiplier has exponential dependency.

The other question for me is, is it worth the effort?

Lot of other engineers are using Vbe multiplier for decades and it seems to work - but there are also problems like temperature drift and need for thermal compensation (bias transistor MUST have the same temperature like output transistors).

I find the solution very good, specially for class A. If fewer elements are wanted, with same functionality, just use OpAmp and one transistor.

Back to original question:

As already mentioned, this is differential amplifier and it regulates the voltage VCE on transistor TR13 so, that Vref is equal to the sum of voltages on resistors R16 and R17.

Actually, this is constant current circuit with voltage control. Difference to standard circuit, is that output is controlled with parallel connected transistor.

Iquiescent = Vref / R16+R17